# Good design of server reinitialization in multithreaded setting in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

We are developing a C++ library with a C interface. In the C interface, there is:

- a function to initialize the library (`Init()` — construct the object that implements the functionality with given parameters);
- a function to de-initialize the library (`DeInit()`  — destruct that object), and;
- a couple of functions that just call the corresponding methods on the object (say `Foo()` and `Bar()`).

The class itself is thread-safe, but I want the C interface (i.e. `Init()`, `DeInit()`, `Foo()` and `Bar()`) to be thread-safe, too.

There is a single global variable -- the pointer to the class instance. Which of the following approaches would you consider the best? Would you do it in a yet different way?

1. There is a global `unique_ptr<T>` together with a global read/write lock. `Foo()` and `Bar()` lock it for reading; `Init()` and `DeInit()` lock it for writing.
2. Use a semaphore to track the number of threads using the instance. If `DeInit()` is called, wait on the semaphore until its count is 0.
3. Use `shared_ptr` semantics. The global `shared_ptr` can be changed, but the object will not be deleted until there are no users. This has the potential to overload the system, as there can be several instances (consuming a lot of memory) serving the needs of the pending operations, as Init() does not (and does not need to) wait until the pending operations are completed.

The option 3 seems to be easiest to implement using C++11. Correct me if I am mistaken or too vague.

EDIT
Clarification: Calls to Init() and DeInit() are changing the global pointer, so they should be prevented from running concurrently by means of a lock. Foo() and Bar() should be able to run concurrently.

EDIT Clarification By C interface, I mean the set of functions implementing the C interface. I want this set of functions to be thread safe.

Comment: Format your post please. You've been here for two and a half years, so you know how to do it. If you've forgotten, the preview pane shows you how your post will look (and it clearly doesn't look right) before you post it.

Comment: Sorry, will do it that way next time.

Comment: What should the behaviour of the library be when multiple threads are calling `Init()` *and* `Deinit()`?

Comment: @quamrana - I'd be interested to know that too! Seems to me that there's a mix-up somewhere: Init will create a new instance but there's a global var/"pointer" to it; each call to Init changes the pointer (what happens to the previous instance). I think that it should either allow one Init and only one init call (singleton) or Init should return an opaque instance "handle" to the caller (and it's up to the caller to manage it and call DeInit(handle).

Comment: All those approaches would be valid. Have to leave now, will think about it, but my feeling is that it has no relation to the problem itself (i.e. excluding calling DeInit while there are users of the instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, having a global variable, even a hidden one, is to be avoided if possible. Since your class is already thread safe, do away with locking altogether by returning a handle to the users. They are best placed to know what to do about it. Then write good documentation and let the users decide what and how to synchronize. For example:

```
void *handle = Init(...);
void *value = Foo(handle, ...);
int status = Bar(handle, ...);
DeInit(handle, ...);
```

If the library user code is in C++ it is trivial to wrap this into a C++ smart handler class with synchronized accesses if required. If the user knows somehow there will never be concurrent accesses (user code might run in a single thread for example) then no need to lock anything.

[Edit: typos]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly.

you can do that by using a static mutex/CS on your c++ class that will stop external threads from running any of the internal functions simultaneously

your question confuses me because i don't see how an interface can be thread-safe. as long as the interface does not do any logic it will be reliant on the code that is being run through it.

if your interface is performing some logic that is thread dependent then maybe you should consider moving that logic into the library side where you have more control of what else is happening in your code.

If this answer is completely unrelated to your question then apologies in advance.

Comment: The methods of the class are already able to run simultaneously. It is the interaction of the wrappers of these methods (called Foo() and Bar() for simplicity) with the C functions Init() and DeInit(), which construct and destruct the object. I am not sure a read/write lock has the right semantics and C++ even does not have a read/write lock in the standard library, so I am looking for an alternative that is threadsafe, but not using a rw lock.

Comment: "and C++ even does not have a read/write lock in the standard library"  see std::lock_guard/ std::lock etc. (C++11)

Comment: These are lock guards on a mutex. The semantics of a mutex is to lock for both reading and writing simultaneously. A read/write lock can lock for reading and writing separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at an answer given that you want a single global variable:

```
//Lib.h

//extern "c" stuff

void Init(void);

type1 Foo(void);
type2 Bar(void);

void Deinit(void);


//Lib.cpp
#include "Lib.h"

// includes for mutex etc.

namespace {
    class RealObject{
    public:
        RealObject(){}
        type1 Foo();
        type2 Bar();
    };
    RealObject* getObject(){
        static RealObject obj;
        return &obj;
    }
    Mutex mutex;
}

void Init(void){
    Lock lock(mutex);
    getObject();
}

type1 Foo(void){
    return getObject()->Foo();
}
type2 Bar(void){
    return getObject()->Bar();
}

void Deinit(void){}
```

This assumes that all clients **always** call `Init()` before any combinations of `Foo` or `Bar`

The very first `Init()` creates the global instance and `Deinit()` is a nop.

The mutex is present simply to make a Singleton.